# Python/Flask Timed Event Configuration Page

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a Python application that will execute certain code repeatedly on a timer when that timer is enabled. I'd like to be able to enable/disable the timer from a web page. I've been attempting to do this with Flask and the sched event scheduler, to no avail. I'm not sure if either Flask or sched are the right tools for the job, and I appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

My Code So Far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sched, time
app = Flask(__name__)

cameraScheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def triggerCamera(sc):
    print('Picture Taken')
    cameraScheduler.enter(5,1,triggerCamera,(sc,))


@app.route('/', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def settings():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if(request.form.getlist('timer') == ['true']):
            cameraScheduler.enter(5,1,triggerCamera,(cameraScheduler,))
            cameraScheduler.run
        else:
            cameraScheduler.cancel()
            
    return render_template("settings.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try actually calling the scheduler `cameraScheduler.run`**()** (you are missing the parentheses there).